# Undefined error message in component React

Tags: reactjs, crud, mern

I'm attempting to upload an image to the Cloudinary website, and then continue on to display them on my webpage, however I keep receiving errors in my code. This is the error I'm receiving.
[image]

And this is my current code.

```
// ImageDisplay.js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function ProfileImage() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    imagePreviewUrl: "",
    picFile: null,
  });
  let fileInput =  React.createRef();

  // Activates user file input to set div
  const editProfilePic = () => {
    fileInput.current.click();
  };
  // Handles the image that was input by user
  const handleImageChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let inFile = e.target.files[0];
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      setValues({ ...values, picFile: inFile, imagePreviewUrl: reader.result });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(inFile);
  };

  // Call the API Backend, will describe this later
  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    // response stores the response back from the API
    response = await axios.post(`/storage/upload`, form_data).catch((error) => {
      alert(
        "Error occurred while uploading picture, try uploading a smaller image size or try again later."
      );
      return;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => editProfilePic()}>
        <input
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
          onChange={handleImageChange}
          ref={fileInput}
        />
        <img src={imagePreviewUrl} alt="..." style={{ objectFit: "cover" }} />
      </div>
      <button onclick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: in handleSubmit (line30) response is not declared it should be "let response = ... ", also for form-data, you have to pass it as an agument after clicking the button.
for <img src={imagePreviewUrl} it should be "<img src={value.simagePreviewUrl}..."

Answer (score -1):

The problem is simple.

You have undeclared variables.
response, from _data, imagePreviewUrl.

Apparently you want to upload images to the storage using axios by post, I recommend you read this examples https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/axios+file+upload

**Solution**

**First change the function handleSubmit to this**

```
  const handleSubmit = async () => {
  //Solution fixe form_data adding your picFile to FormData
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("image", values.picFile);
    // response stores the response back from the API
  //Solution fixed error response applying const to variable response
  const  response = await axios.post(`/storage/upload`, form_data).catch((error) => {
      alert(
        "Error occurred while uploading picture, try uploading a smaller image size or try again later."
      );
      return;
    });
  };
```

**Change the imagePreviewUrl**
replace this

```
 <img src={imagePreviewUrl} alt="..." style={{ objectFit: "cover" }} />
```

**Solution:**

```
 <img src={values.imagePreviewUrl} alt="..." style={{ objectFit: "cover" }} />
```